# How wordvector algorithm find similarity between words?

Tags: nlp, recurrent-neural-network, word2vec

What is the intuition behind? can someone briefly explain why we extract the output of hidden layer in wordvector  network architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word-vectors typically used are actually from a "projection layer" of the neural-network.

That projection-layer essentially converts individual word indexes ("one-hot" representations, single ints from 0 to V-1, where V is the count of known unique words) into **input** vectors (dense embeddings, with N non-zero continuous dimensions, where N is much smaller than V).

Those input vectors are fed to a shallow neural-network that tries to predict words' neighboring words.

It turns out that when you force those dense-embeddings (and internal neural-network weights) to become better and better at predicting their neighbors, word-vectors for related words get closer to each other, as a general matter of how related they are.

And further, the simultaneous interleaved attempt to do this for all words and training examples tends to also create meaningful "neighborhoods" and "directions" within the final arrangement – allowing the interesting "meaning arithmetic" that lets word-vector operations often solve analogies like `man : king :: woman : __?__`.